# Probability of a duplicate when sampling random pairs from a set ("the lunch tag problem")

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, sampling

Consider a set $S$ of $n$ elements. Define a "full pairing" of $S$ as some division of the set into unordered subsets of size 2, such that every element of $S$ is contained in exactly one subset. (For simplicity, suppose $n$ is even.)

Suppose that we conduct a random full pairing of $S$; that is, we randomly assign all elements of $S$ to an unordered pair s.t. every element is assigned to exactly one pair and there are $n/2$ pairs. Suppose further that $k$ unique pairs are already known, and it is our naive hope that this random pairing process does **not** yield any of these $k$ known pairs.

Question: What is the probability that this random full pairing contains at least one duplicate from the $k$ known pairs?

---

Example: Suppose $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. One full pairing would be $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\}\}$. Suppose that we observed this full pairing, hence $k=3$ pairs observed since they are all unique. What is the probability that a new, entirely random full pairing of $S$ yields at least one duplicate compared to the already-observed pairs?

For background: this is inspired by the case of a "lunch tag" program of sorts, where individuals sign up to get randomly paired to have lunch (etc.) together. Let's consider the *lunch tag problem*, the problem of creating these assignments over and over again, from the same fixed pool, while preventing "repeat tags" if at all possible (i.e. while maximizing new tags). I have been curious about some intuition behind this lunch tag process. For example, as you iterate through the process, how quickly does the number of possible assignments (constrained to those which have NOT been observed/assigned before) shrink to zero? I've done my best above to precisely frame the desired intuition-building question, but apologies if it is unclear.

My thoughts so far: if $k=1$, this doesn't seem too bad. Let's say $P^{*}$ is the known pair, and $P_1, P_2, \dots, P_{N/2}$ are the draws from one random full pairing. Then $pr(\text{duplicate}) = pr(P_1=P^{*} \text{ or } P_2=P^{*} \text{ or } \dots \text{ or } P_{n/2} = P^{*})$ $= pr(P_1=P^{*}) + pr(P_2=P^{*}) + \dots pr(P_{n/2} = P^{*})$ $= \frac{n}{2}pr(P=P^{*})$ for any randomly-drawn $P$. Since there are $C^{n}_2 = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ possible pairs, I think that this probability $pr(P=P^{*}) = \frac{2}{n(n-1)}$. Hence the final answer should be $\frac{1}{n-1}$. I'm stuck on how to extend this to $k>1$ though, since that would introduce more than one possible "match" or duplicate, which would make the probabilities dependent and more complicated ... of course I'm not 100% sure this line of thinking is correct anyways! :)

P.S. would also welcome answers that can generalize to $m$-sized subsets (and for simplicity $m$ divides $n$) rather than just pairs!

---

Edit: I spent some time trying to simulate this process numerically. For each $n$, the code keeps increasing $k$ until it's unable to create the set of unique known pairs of size $k$. At 20 iterations per parameter configuration $(N,k)$, the estimation still appears a bit noisy. But here's what I've found if it may help.

Estimated probability of a random full pairing containing at least one duplicate: [view 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13qsG.png), [view 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCBIU.png), [view 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ps7nQ.png). Interestingly, it seems that the maximum number of known pairs that can be drawn while still retaining uniqueness is $k_{\text{max}}=n^2/2 -n$. (Quadratic regression on the simulated $k_{max}$ suggested these parameters which resulted in an exact fit.) I thought this was surprising but hopefully it's not too obvious!

[Python code](https://pastebin.com/raw/d0t4d626) (originally a jupyter notebook). It could use some polishing up—e.g. if it were informed by the maximum value on $k$, then it could run much more quickly—but it's what I've got for now.

Comment: Are the $k$ previous pairs all disjoint?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! The $k$ previous pairs are unique. I'm not entirely sure how to define "disjoint" for this set of pairs though. They do *not* have to be "pairwise disjoint", in that a plausible collection of pairs could be $\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\}\}$. I've updated the question to clarify this but let me know if I should consider disjointed-ness in some other way.

Comment: I asked because the probability you're looking for could depend on how exactly the previous pairs overlap with each other, whereas it sounds like you're hoping the count $k$ of unique pairs is all we need to know about them. Should we assume the set of previous pairs is drawn uniformly from all $\binom{\binom n2}k$ possibilities?

Comment: In your post you write that "every element of $S$ is contained in exactly one subset." If that's the case, how could a possible collection of pairs be $\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\}\}$?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you might be interested in [round-robin scheduling](https://nrich.maths.org/1443).

Comment: @Karl: Aah, I see. I think yes, let's assume that the previous pairs are drawn uniformly.

In formulating the question, the $k$ perspective seemed to make sense to me as an important variable. But as far as it relates to the motivating problem ("lunch tag"), $k$ is more general than necessary. Practically, what I would imagine to happen in a standard "tag" process, is that the $k$ "known pairs" are actually the history of previous "full pairings." So we would always be dealing with $k=tn/2$ where $t$ is the number of iterations of the tag process. ...

Comment: [continued] Since a proper lunch tag process in this world will generate pairs without repeating throughout the entire history of $tn/2$ pairs, then I would *think* that the outcome of this process after any number of iterations could be considered as a uniform draw from the distribution of all "$k$ unique pairs" possibilities. Does that seem right? (p.s. thanks for the link!)

Comment: @MatthewH.: sorry if this was unclear. The "every element of $S$ is contained in exactly one subset" definition was to describe a "random full pairing." This was imagining a new full pairing, after $k$ other pairs have already been known. As discussed above, these $k$ pairs could overlap in one of their two elements.

So in the "lunch tag" context, the random full pairing can be thought of as a naive attempt at creating a new iteration of the "tag" by randomly assigning pairs. The known pairs can be thought of as the participants which had been assigned to each other in previous iterations.